# initialising an array with the content of a text file in C

Tags: c++, c, arrays, visual-c++

I wrote the code below to read data from a text file and store the values in an array.   my code is not reading the file.

library headers being used

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
```

my main

```
int main()
{   
FILE *fpoo;
float NumArr[5];
```

//i equally tried "c:\Fly_u.txt"

```
fpoo= fopen ("Fly_u.txt","r");
if(fpoo!=NULL)

    for (int i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        fscanf(fpoo,"%d\n",NumArr[i]);
    {
else
{
    printf("me");

}
for (int i=0;i<6;i++)
{
    printf("%f",NumArr[i]);
}


fclose(fpoo);
_getche();
return 0;
}
```

//content of the text file is as follows

```
0.99247
0.14727
-0.00041387
-1.737
0.20475
-0.052151
0.14755
-0.0233
-0.32606
0.092085
0.059199
-0.025587
0.0097565
0.13639
0.12007
```

Comment: I don't think c++ tag is applicable here.

Comment: In a twenty line program you've used on one C++ feature, which is the declaration of the variable `i` in your for loop. If this is how you want to program then it might be better to start learning C instead of C++.

Comment: @jahhaj: C99 allowed for the declaration of variables in (relatively) arbitrary locations in a function, so even that does not apply.  This is C

Comment: @EdS. Although that is correct (and it isn't exactly recent development as it's been a while since '99; some now-popular languages weren't even released back then!), the `visual-c++` tag complicates things a bit, as Microsoft's C compiler is strictly C89-only (AFAIK). So OP probably had to run the compiler in C++ mode.

Comment: @eq-: Yes, VS only implements C89, a constant source of frustration for me...

Answer (score 7):

The use of [`fscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) is incorrect:

- you need to use the format specifier for `float` which is `%f`, not `int`
- you need to pass the address of a `float` (i.e. a `float*`), not a `float`

Change:

```
fscanf(fpoo,"%d\n",NumArr[i]);
```

to:

```
fscanf(fpoo,"%f\n", &NumArr[i]);
```

`fscanf()` returns the number of successful assignments, which in this case should be `1`. Recommend checking inputs were successfully read before attempting to use them later.

If you specify `"Fly_u.txt"` as the file name then it *must* be in the same directory as the working directory of the process. Remember to esacpe `'\'` when constructing paths, or just use `'/'` (which also works on Windows).

The `for` loops will result in undefined behaviour as array indexes run from `0` to `N - 1`.  So for `float NumArr[5];` the valid indexes are `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` but the terminating condition on both `for` loops is `i < 6` which use an index of `5`: illegal. Either increase the size of `NumArr` or adjust the terminating condition on the `for` loops.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
fscanf(fpoo,"%f\n",&NumArr[i]);
              ^    ^
              ^    ^
```

that is, pass the address of the variables that you want to store the data in. Note the `%f` instead of `%d` also.

You don't specify the problem, but if you are having trouble with the return from `fopen` check your file path and try passing the full path to your file. As @hmjd says, what you do now assumes that the file exists in the same location as your executable.

Answer (score 0):

'I equally tried "c:\Fly_u.txt"' This is wrong because \ has a special meaning in C strings. What you should have used is `"c:\\Fly_u.txt"`.